# AWS Fargate - How to get the public ip address of task by using python boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-ecs, serverless, aws-fargate

I am creating new fargate task by using the following python script.

```
import boto3
import json


def handler():
  client = boto3.client('ecs')
  response = client.run_task(
  cluster='fargate-learning', # name of the cluster
  launchType = 'FARGATE',
  taskDefinition='fargate-learning:1', # replace with your task definition name and revision
  count = 1,
  platformVersion='LATEST',
  networkConfiguration={
        'awsvpcConfiguration': {
            'subnets': [
                'subnet-0a024d8ac87668b64', # replace with your public subnet or a private with NAT
            ],
            'assignPublicIp': 'ENABLED'
        }
    })

  print(response)
  return str(response)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    handler()
```

And here is the response I am getting from boto3.

https://jsonblob.com/5faf3ae6-bc31-11ea-8cae-53bd90c38587

I can not see the public ip address in response although the script is assigning the public ip address and I can see it on website.

[image: aws fargate ip address]

So, how can I get this public ip address by using boto3?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be done in **two steps**:

1. Use [describe_tasks](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ecs.html#ECS.Client.describe_tasks) to get ENI id associated with your fargate `awsvpc` interface. The value of eni, e.g. `eni-0c866df3faf8408d0`, will be given in `attachments` and `details` from the result of the call.
2. Once you have the eni, then you can use [EC2.NetworkInterface](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.NetworkInterface). For example:

```
eni_id = 'eni-0c866df3faf8408d0' # from step 1

eni = boto3.resource('ec2').NetworkInterface(eni_id)

print(eni.association_attribute['PublicIp'])
```

Comment: @john No problem. Glad I could help.:-)

Answer (score 4):

Tried implementing @Marcin 's answers as a function. Hope this can be helpful

```py
def get_service_ips(cluster, tasks):
    tasks_detail = ecs.describe_tasks(
        cluster=cluster,
        tasks=tasks
    )
    
    # first get the ENIs
    enis = []
    for task in tasks_detail.get("tasks", []):
        for attachment in task.get("attachments", []):
            for detail in attachment.get("details", []):
                if detail.get("name") == "networkInterfaceId":
                    enis.append(detail.get("value"))
   
    # now the ips
    ips = []
    for eni in enis:
        eni_resource = boto3.resource("ec2").NetworkInterface(eni)
        ips.append(eni_resource.association_attribute.get("PublicIp"))

    return ips
```

as a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/drewbo/fe1c719eeac316f573e2ef2bc9c47a37).